# Using a Correlated Value with SQLAlchemy's Bulk Insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psql

I'm working on submitting a couple values into my PSQL database through SQLAlchemy. I have two tables, parent and child. Right now I go through and create a list of rows to be inserted into each database using the execute many [example seen here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements) . This works fine and I can insert into the parent and child tables efficiently. However, I also need the child to have a foreign key pointing to the parent it uses. With this in mind, I've been trying to use a [Correlated Update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#correlated-updates) . My code looks like this:

```
select_pid = select([Parent.id]).where(
Parent.parentname == json_data["parent"]).limit(1)

child_list.append({"parentforeignid": select_pid})
```

There's other things being inserted. Just showed the foreign id for brevity's sake.

Finally once the list is populated, I run:

```
db.engine.execute(Child.__table__.insert(), child_list)
```

which gives this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Select'
```

and shows the field as:

```
<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x10c91a390; Select object>
```

Again, if I don't use the select statement this bulk insert runs fine, but then there's no foreign key pointing to the parent. This is because the parent is usually not created when I make the child values. Anybody know how I can make this work? Or how to better approach the problem? Another solution I had was iterating through the child list and querying for the parent id then before inserting the child, but that seems cumbersome.